# CRM 2015 setValue() triggering onChange

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to use the built in setValue() funtion in CRM 2015 to change a field back to null if a confirm() command comes back as false. The field that triggers the confirm() is also the field I am trying to set to null.

The code is as follows:

```
if (optionSetField.getValue() == 805430000 /*YES*/) {

        var tempBoolean = confirm("Test", "test Title")
        if (tempBoolean == false) {

            optionSetField.setValue(null)
        }
```

The field I am trying to set to null is an option set field with "yes" and "no" as the available options. I found this preferable to use over a bit field as it meant I did not require a default value.

Upon the code triggering and the user clicking 'Cancel' the setValue(null) triggers the onChange event, which despite the field supposedly being set to null asks for confirmation again. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a potential bug? Is there an alternate suggestion for what I am doing?

According to the Microsoft tech docs setValue() should not trigger onChange events, but clearly this is not the case. Anyone's insight would be helpful!

See here for the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_setValue

Comment: it should only trigger an onChange event if you are calling "FireOnChange"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `confirmDialog`, since it's callback-based it should allow the field to update itself properly.

> ```
> Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog(message, yesCallback, noCallback)
> ```

So like this

```
if (optionSetField.getValue() === 805430000) {
    Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog("Test", function(){
        optionSetField.setValue(null);
    });
}
```

This would also work on tablets (confirm, on the other hand, won't)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this bit on information, however unfortunately it doesn't stop the looping problem.On clicking 'Cancel' the field recognises it has been changed and then triggers the event again, however before the field is set to a value of 'null' the function reads the field as having the previous value in it and asks for confirmation once again.

Comment: This bit of code works perfectly on 2013sp1 so it smells like bug. I'll come back and update the answer after I'm able to check a 2015 environment.

Comment: What happens in the first "if" after you set the field to null? Have you debugged it using the console mode? If the field is set to null, that check shouldn't pass.

Comment: My first "if" evaluates to false correctly the second time around after setting the field to null, and doesn't ask confirmation repeatedly. Still haven't got my hands on a 2015 environment to check.

Comment: If it's the setValue that triggers the onchange and the SDK says it shouldn't, I'd call that a bug. Please report it to connect and keep your fingers crossed someone thinks it's an important one, the selction of which bugs are remedied is unfortunately very arbitrary...

Answer (score 0):

I've had CRM 2015 U1 Turbo forms trigger onchange events, when it shouldn't be according the the setValue Documentation.  CRM 2016 Update 1 appears to have resolved this issue for me, although I have been unable to find a bug fix listed anywhere in Microsoft's support documentation.

This is the active connect case: https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/2527691

Comment: I assume it solves the problem only for online because on-permise SP1 still has this issue. Also connect link doesn't work.